# Eclipse IDE running error

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I have downloaded Eclipse for JAVA developers from their site
and inserted to ini file:

```
-vm 
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
```

But when I run a eclipse.exe I have another frustrated message:

```
    ---------------------------
Eclipse
---------------------------
Java was started but returned exit code=13
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar D:\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash D:\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.2.1.v201209141800\splash.bmp
-launcher D:\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library D:\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813\eclipse_1503.dll
-startup D:\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 14a4_5c
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-vm c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar D:\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

What the matter? How to fix it ?

Comment: the problem is eclipse imho, try netbeans or intellij

Comment: I can't I need Eclipse for erlIDE plug-in

Comment: they both have erlang plugins available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the correct version of JDK installed for eclipse.?
If you have a 64 bit eclipse downloaded use the 64 bit JDK.

From your question it seems that you have the 32 bit JDK

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
```

and eclipse seems to be 64 bit

```
-arch x86_64
```